# Select -> Refer to itself (currently created list)

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, select

Is there a way to refer to the `List (IEnumerable)` that is created by the `Select` method while being created (inside the method)?

I have a Dictionary that looks like this:

```
Dictionary<char, char> d = new Dictionary<char, char>() 
{ 
  {'a', 'b'},
  {'b', 'a'},
  {'c', 'd'},
  {'d', 'c'},
  //...
};
```

It gets converted to a string via `string.Join("", d.Select(...))`.
The duplicated values in the Dictionary (ab and ba) get sorted out.
I've tried this:

```
                                   //Checks for an earlier swapped duplicate........If not, select it
d.Select(x => !enumerable.Contains(x.Value.ToString() + x.Key.ToString()) ? x.Key.ToString() + x.Value.ToString() : string.Empty);
```

Here, "enumerable" refers the list, that is being created by the Select method but I haven't found a way to do so.

The expected end result should look like: `"abcd"` not `"abbacddc"` like with just joining the keys and values.

I could solve this with a for loop but this requires extra code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can use `Aggregate` and `Distinct`:

```
var enumerable = d.Aggregate(string.Empty,
    (acc, kv) => string.Concat(acc,
                               kv.Key,
                               kv.Value))
                  .Distinct();
```

`enumerable` Will be an `IEnumerable<char>` with the desired output.